# C# How to get POST form value from context.Request.InputStream

Tags: c#, http, parsing, post

i want to make an application using c# where it can receive any post send to it.
For example when i posted `<input name="inp1" type="text" value="something">` from html, it should get inp1 as something.
So far, i have looking for every question, and got me to this.

```
    private void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
            {
                // Get the data from the HTTP stream
                var body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

                byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ACK");
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                context.Response.KeepAlive = false;

                NameValueCollection coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(body);
                Debug.Write(body);
}
```

and here is the output:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryDykOSF9gSjwBSbS2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inp1"

something
------WebKitFormBoundaryDykOSF9gSjwBSbS2--
```

How to get something pure like `"form["inp1"] = something"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of throwing away `col1`, use it to obtain all the keys and values in the collection, and format them into a string for output. Here is an example:

```
 NameValueCollection coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(body);
 var response = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (var key in col1.AllKeys)
 {
     response.Append(String.Format(@"form[""{0}""] = {1}\r\n", key, col1[key]));  //Edit the format string to taste
 }
 Debug.Write(response.ToString());
```

Comment: sorry for late comment, but thankyou very much, it really helps me,,,