# Asp.net Webforms: Webhook receiver: How read data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webhooks

Please take a look at this thread :
[Asp.net Webforms: Create webhook receiver for typeform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584656/asp-net-webforms-create-webhook-receiver-for-typeform)
Here is my webHook in asp.net WebForm :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Web_Site
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebHook
    /// </summary>
    public class WebHook : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

            try
            {
                string body = string.Empty;
                context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

                using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                {
                    body = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
                {
                    dynamic json = JObject.Parse(body);

                    // Access the webhook payload data ie, get first answer:
                    var answers = json.form_response.asnwers;
                    //Console.WriteLine(answers);
                    context.Response.Write("<script>console.log('" + answers + "');</script>");
                }

                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

                context.Response.Write("WebHook Handler is working fine...");

                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.SuppressContent = true;
                context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

                //context.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write("<script>console.log('Error is WebHook.ashx Is : " + ex.ToString().Replace("'", "_").Replace("\"", "_").Replace("\r\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\n").Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "');</script>");
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is body is not json.
Here is body string :

> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id" 61dab40eedc5663a2436f726
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="txid"
> a28fc26550cea7a67a9725625a3e476c4df9118f066f6360b4fbaeb633a789f9
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="explorer_url"
> https://coinremitter.com/tcn/tx/a28fc26550cea7a67a9725625a3e476c4df9118f066f6360b4fbaeb633a789f9?from=coinremitter
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="merchant_id" 61d97b1a7e7f76732e105a37
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type" send --------------------------8c59580547b0689a
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="coin_short_name" TCN
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wallet_id" 61daa2ad7cc73878a6383a42
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wallet_name" TestWallet110
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address" RKKxYDkvWp8UUjUu2sYgdfPMMbfmqYDSa1
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="amount" 1.20000000
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="confirmations" 1
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date" 2022-01-09 10:08:14
> --------------------------8c59580547b0689a--

I am confused about this body.
How can i read it?

I have error in this line :

> dynamic json = JObject.Parse(body);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# How to get POST form value from context.Request.InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295180/c-sharp-how-to-get-post-form-value-from-context-request-inputstream)

Comment: But why are you using http handler of .net framework because it legacy now? Try to use .net core instead. You can create simple API which can take any kind of parameter and response in any kind. Default it supports XML and Json

Comment: @शेखर That answer not help about this body.

Comment: when you are trying this `NameValueCollection coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(body);`  are you getting some error? It's not Json it's confirm. It could be `multipart/form-data`. Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Here is some [MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) which can help.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640943/request-body-of-httpcontext-how-grab-values) solved my problem, I voted this question as duplicate. Please close it.

Comment: @शेखर thanks for the comments - Your links was useful. God bless you man.