# Request body of HttpContext - How grab values

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

Here is request body of `HttpContext` :

```
string body = string.Empty;
context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    body = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id" 61dab40eedc5663a2436f726
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="txid"
> a28fc26550cea7a67a9725625a3e476c4df9118f066f6360b4fbaeb633a789f9
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="explorer_url"
> https://coinremitter.com/tcn/tx/a28fc26550cea7a67a9725625a3e476c4df9118f066f6360b4fbaeb633a789f9?from=coinremitter
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="merchant_id" 61d97b1a7e7f76732e105a37
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type" send --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="coin_short_name" TCN
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wallet_id" 61daa2ad7cc73878a6383a42
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wallet_name" TestWallet110
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address" RKKxYDkvWp8UUjUu2sYgdfPMMbfmqYDSa1
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="amount" 0.50000000
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="confirmations" 3
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date" 2022-01-09 10:08:14
> --------------------------c6fec46ab7e1fd1e--

As you see this string is not json.
How can i grab address & amount & confirmations & date from this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of not using request stream, I think because the content type of request is `form-data` you can use `Form` function on request like this:

```
var address = context.Request.Form["address"].ToString();
var amount = context.Request.Form["amount"].ToString();
//and so on for other data
```